# Registry script to enable automatic updates for Adobe/Java

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-xp, windows-registry, automation

Is there a registry script or a one click system to enable automatic updates for the following?

- Adobe Flash
- Java
- Adobe Reader

This way I can quickly enable these services to download and install on their own

Answer (score 0):

[Adobe Flash Player Distribution](http://www.adobe.com/products/flashplayer/distribution3.html)

[Adobe Reader for Windows](http://www.adobe.com/support/downloads/product.jsp?product=10&platform=Windows)

LoadFlash.ps1:

```
$userAgent = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.2;)"
$client = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$UrlPath01 = "http://download.macromedia.com/get/flashplayer/current/licensing/win/"

$DstPath = "D:\VBS\PS-01-Internet-Load1\"

mkdir $DstPath -force

$FlashAcX = "install_flash_player_11_active_x.msi"
$FlashPlr = "install_flash_player_11_plugin.msi"

$client.Headers.Add("user-agent", $userAgent)

$client.DownloadFile($UrlPath01+$FlashAcX,$DstPath+$FlashAcX)
Write-Host $FlashAcX" download!"

$client.DownloadFile($UrlPath01+$FlashPlr,$DstPath+$FlashPlr)
Write-Host $FlashPlr" download!"
```

Install Adobe Flash:

```
msiexec /i install_flash_player_11_active_x.msi /qn /norestart
msiexec /i install_flash_player_11_plugin.msi /qn /norestart
```

Install Java:

```
START /WAIT jre-6u30-windows-i586.exe /s ADDLOCAL=jrecore IEXPLORER=1 MOZILLA=1 JAVAUPDATE=0 AUTOUPDATECHECK=0 REBOOT=ReallySuppress
IF EXIST "%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\Desktop\Java Web Start.LNK" DEL "%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\Desktop\Java Web Start.LNK"
IF EXIST "%PUBLIC%\Desktop\Java Web Start.LNK" DEL "%PUBLIC%\Desktop\Java Web Start.LNK"
IF EXIST "%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\Start Menu\Programs\Java Web Start\Java Web Start.LNK" RD /Q /S "%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\Start Menu\Programs\Java Web Start"
IF EXIST "%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Java Web Start\Java Web Start.LNK" RD /Q /S "%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Java Web Start"
:: Java Configure on x86 systems
REG ADD "HKLM\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Plug-in\1.6.0_24" /v HideSystemTrayIcon /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f
REG ADD "HKLM\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Update\Policy" /v EnableJavaUpdate /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f
REG ADD "HKLM\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Update\Policy" /v EnableAutoUpdateCheck /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f
REG ADD "HKLM\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Update\Policy" /v NotifyDownload /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f
REG ADD "HKLM\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Update\Policy" /v NotifyInstall /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f
REG DELETE "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run" /v SunJavaUpdateSched /f
```

Install Adobe Reader:

```
AdbeRdr_1100_en_US.exe /sAll /msi /norestart ALLUSERS=1 EULA_ACCEPT=YES
```